# is the init method not working properly in swift

Tags: swift

With the code below, the local songs variable is never able to be iterated despite all the checks to the contrary  ( println shows the value stored ).  The other thing is that the Xcode debugger seems to jump all over the place in the init method.

```
let gLibraryManager = LibraryManager()

class LibraryManager {

var Songs = Dictionary<String, String>()

init() {
    println("struct being initialized from NSDefaults")
    let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults();
    var result:AnyObject = userDefaults.objectForKey(LIKED_LIST)
    println(result)
    var local = result as? Dictionary<String,String>
    if local != nil {
        println("local not nil: \(local!)")
        for (id,title) in local!  {
            Songs[id] = title
        }
        if Songs.count > 0 {
            println("NSDefaults detected: \(Songs)")
        } else {
            println("no NSDefaults detected.  Initializing empty")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the actual error you are getting? What do you mean the `songs` variable cannot be iterated? Do you mean that the for block is never executed? Have you verified if the user defaults is actually returning a non-empty dictionary?

Comment: Show us the output of your prints

Comment: Also, are you actually using `Songs` and `songs` as two different vars...

Comment: struct being initialized from NSDefaults
{
    3806754377931625544 = Wewhocannotbenamed;
}
local not nil: [3806754377931625544: Wewhocannotbenamed]
no NSDefaults detected.  Initializing empty

Comment: verified nsdefaults has a value.   two separate variables.  i separated them because directly settings the Songs was not working.   The odd thing is that this code seems to work in a different project.

Comment: @TommyFannon, you first error message indicates that there is nothing in the NSDefaults

Answer (score 0):

ok.  i figured out what is was.

I had set the Swift Compiler - Code Generation. Optimization level to -Fastest.  This was to prevent the extremely slow creation of Dictionaries.

However, it appears this breaks the ability to iterate structures.

It also seems to resolve the weird bouncing around of breakpoints.

This was a needle in a haystack that tooks many hours.  I guess the moral of the story is not to mess with compiler flags yet.